# How do I create a surface plot in python using values from a text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a 3D surface plot from a text file that has four coloumns and 700 rows. I have written the code below to generate that plot, but I constantly keep getting the following error:

```
invalid value encountered in true_divide

z = (x*y*mlim)/(x*y)

raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")

ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

Here is my code

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


f2 = open('openfile.txt', 'r')
i6 = list()
i9 = list()
i10 = list ()
count = 0
while True:
    a = f2.readline()
    if not a: break
    v = a.split()
    i6.append(float(v[0]))
    i9.append(float(v[1]))
    i10.append(float(v[3]))
    count = count + 1


mlim = np.array(i6)
ira = np.array(i9)
dec = np.array(i10)

x = ira
y = dec
z = (x*y*mlim)/(x*y)



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
plt.savefig('filesave.png')
plt.close()
```

How do I solve this? 
I have also attached an image of what the actual text file looks like
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ARs6.png)

Thank you.

Comment: The error that you are seeing `invalid value encountered in true_divide` is because in some of the cases your denominator in `z = (x*y*mlim)/(x*y)` is becoming zero. It can be easily verified from the values of `x` and `y` as given in the text file. Have some provision to handle those cases in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To plot a 3D surface, a wire frame in your case, you must create a meshgrid (a.k.a a matrix) before so as to map this in you function `(x*y*mlim)/(x*y)`.

The following alteration may fix your problem:

```
# More of your code above this

x = ira
y = dec

# Create a meshgrid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# Now you can build you z array using the correct mapping
# Note that mlim variable works as an scalar
z = (X*Y*mlim)/(X*Y)
```

The comment of @Koustav above is pertinent too. It is important check for null/zero values in case of division.